# Not showing value in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I am trying to change currency code in paypal form.
But i have problems. I make this with javascript and
still dont work right.
I have been thinking like this, when i put number in 
input id="A" then will show me "USD in input id="currency_code".
And when i change this selection to "EUR" show me EUR in input id="currency_code".
I am sorry if i dont explain, but i am self learner.
I need little help please.

My work:
http://jsfiddle.net/sked/1nrrfkez/

html code:

```
<form > 
<input type="text" size="7" maxlength="4"  id="A" onChange="setPrice()" OnBlur="checkValue(this.value)" />

    <select id="D" class="box" onChange="setPrice()">
       <option value="1" >USD</option>
       <option value="2" >EUR</option>
       <option value="3" >GBP</option>
    </select>

<input id="currency_val" name="currency_code" value="" readonly/>
```

and javascript code:

```
function setPrice () {

var D = parseFloat($_('D').value);
var eur = "EUR";
var result = (+A).toFixed(2);
var result = (+D).toFixed(2);

    $_('currency_val').value = eur;
    $_('currency_code').value = result;
```

});

Comment: what type of code is this?

Comment: please go through some js and jquery example..before you implement it

Comment: You have syntax error (unnecessary `)` at the last line), you have strange `$_` (what is it?), you probably have undefined variable `A`. so it's not surprising that it doesn't work. Do you understand what you are doing?

Comment: As i wrote i am self learner, so sorry if i didnt make it right. Can anyone show me right one or some example.

Comment: Now i change little : http://jsfiddle.net/sked/1nrrfkez/11/

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use, $("#currency_val").val() instead of $("#currency_val").value() to get the value from the input, but there are more mistakes^^

First of all! use unrobustive Javascript, don´t make the mistake an call Javascript code over the HTML TAg´s, let them do over Javascript e.g `$("#A").on("change",setPrice);` instead of `<select id="D" class="box" **onChange="setPrice()"**>`

//The ID Selector needs a "#" sign, use for input fields val instead of value

```
function setPrice () {
var D = parseFloat($('#D').val());
      alert($('#D').val());
var eur = "EUR";
var result = (+A).toFixed(2);
var result = (+D).toFixed(2);

    $('#currency_val').val(eur);
    $('#currency_code').val(result);
```

};

```
$("#A").on("change",setPrice);
$("#D").on("change",setPrice);
```

Comment: Thank you so much now all is working and you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/sked/1nrrfkez/13/